# Authentication key error in notification (FCM Token)

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I am working on notification task to get notification by using FCM with Mysql . In that I have created token, and saved it into the database. But when I click on send push button, it throws this error:

> E/EGL_emulation: tid 3553: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0x9695b9a0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
>
> [Error on application after click on send push button -]

Comment: [Short checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) for English starters.

Comment: <H1>The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentification&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.</H1>              Error 401                                                                      please help me how to solve it...Thanks